# Alternative for nested If else statements in typescript or javascript otherthan switch and ternary operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement, conditional-operator, nested-if

Currently I am using ESLint to reduce the complexity of code, so in order to that I want to reduce my if-else code into less complexity. I have the following code.

```
if (sortBy.length && sortBy == 'updated_at') {
     createQuery
     .distinctOn(['adjustments.updated_at', 'adjustments.id'])
     .orderBy('adjustments.updated_at', order && order.length ? order :  
     DESC')
     .addOrderBy('adjustments.id', order && order.length ? order : 
     'DESC');
} else if (sortBy.length && sortBy == 'default_priority') {
            createQuery
            .distinctOn(['adjustments.default_priority', 
            'adjustments.id', 'adjustments.priority_action_value'])
            .orderBy('adjustments.default_priority', order && 
            order.length ? order : 'DESC')
           .addOrderBy('adjustments.priority_action_value', 'DESC');
   } else {
         createQuery
         .distinctOn(['adjustments.created_at', 'adjustments.id'])
         .orderBy('adjustments.created_at', order && order.length ? 
         order : 'DESC')
         .addOrderBy('adjustments.id', order && order.length ? order 
         : 'DESC');
    }
```

Comment: You could do this `order && order.length ? order : 'DESC'` just once before the `if` statement and then use the result in the several places where you currently have that statement.

Comment: Thanks Scott. It worked. I missed that. Thanks a lot Man. But what if I want to remove the if else statement

Comment: Basically, anything that you are going to do in all cases, should be outside of the `if` statement.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `order?.length ? order : ""`

Here if order exist then it will check for its length.

But here I think `order.length` returns a value so you might write:

```js
    order?.length>0 ? order:""
    order?.length<10 ? order:""
```

Comment: this not answers the OP's requirements OP said no ternary operator or switch case, but you are using ternary operator